# Using text input to search Access number column

Tags: sql, jsp, ms-access

I have a simple search page with this text input form

```
<form name="assetInput" action="assetResult.jsp" method="get">
<input type="text" name="assetNo" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

which takes you to a results page that will search an Access database by the Asset Number you type in the search page. The column's data type is number.

This is the code to get the input from the text box, and my attempt to convert the String to an int.

```
<%
    String assetNumber = request.getParameter("assetNo");
    int assetNum = Integer.parseInt(assetNumber);       
%>
```

My query:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM [Inventory Tracking] WHERE (([Inventory Tracking].AssetNumber) = '"+assetNum+"')");
```

I'm able to search columns from the database whose data type is text, but I keep getting errors when trying to search a number column with a String.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers do not take a delimiter, only text fields.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM [Inventory Tracking] WHERE [Inventory Tracking].AssetNumber = "+assetNum);
```

You could avoid a lot of problems with a parameter.

Comment: Thank you!! I would've never figured out something that simple!